# How can I target an entity that has a period in its type ID? (1.8 minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently making an adventure map with custom mods. My modded mobs have id's like "zssaddon.landOctorok" instead of simply "Zombie". Because of this, commands like `/kill @e[type=zssaddon.landOctorok]` simply do not work, and return saying that the UUID is invalid. I have tried quotes, as well as apostrophies.

Comment: Try doing `zssaddon:landOctorok` instead. It is quite hard to test it since i'd need to mod the game and that is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score -1):

Custom mob IDs will not work with /kill as Minecraft doesn’t  allow them.

Answer (score -1):

You can give the mob a name tag and then for example write:

```
/kill @e[name=zssaddon]
```

and it should die